# Slope powerpivot

Tags: rows, powerpivot

How can I calculate the slope between two columns with the previous five rows in power pivot?

It would be like this in excel:

[image: Example]

Is it possible?

Best regards,
João Macau

Answer (score 0):

The [SLOPE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/slope-function-11fb8f97-3117-4813-98aa-61d7e01276b9) is based on a linear regression so that the slope is calculated as the covariance of `x` and `y` divided by the variance of `x`:

[image: Slope Equation]

In DAX, the calculation for the entire table (rather than just the previous five) would look like this:

```
Slope = 
    VAR AvgX = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Data[Date]), ALL(Data))
    VAR AvgY = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Data[Flow]), ALL(Data))
    RETURN DIVIDE(SUMX(Data, (Data[Date] - AvgX) * (Data[Flow] - AvgY)),
                  SUMX(Data, (Data[Date] - AvgX) * (Data[Date] - AvgX)))
```

In order to get just the previous five, we need to change the filter we use when calculating the averages.

```
Slope = 
    VAR Filtered = TOPN(5, FILTER(Data, Data[Date] <= EARLIER(Data[Date])), Data[Date])
    VAR AvgX = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Data[Date]), Filtered)
    VAR AvgY = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Data[Flow]), Filtered)
    RETURN DIVIDE(SUMX(Filtered, (Data[Date] - AvgX) * (Data[Flow] - AvgY)),
                  SUMX(Filtered, (Data[Date] - AvgX) * (Data[Date] - AvgX)))
```

You can add a condition if you want to only return a value if it has five data points to average:

```
RETURN IF(COUNTROWS(Filtered) < 5, BLANK(), DIVIDE([...]))
```