# How to calculate slopes between two points

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am a beginner to DAX and I am trying to calculate the slopes for each two points of a curve :

(Index = order of X for each User)

| Users | Index | X | Y | SLOPE (calculated) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 4 |  |
| A | 2 | 0,5 | 23 | 38 |
| A | 3 | 1 | 40 | 34 |
| A | 4 | 1,5 | 39 | -2 |
| A | 5 | 2 | 22 | -34 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 9 |  |
| B | 2 | 0,5 | 26 | 34 |
| B | 3 | 1 | 54 | 56 |
| B | 4 | 1,5 | 42 | -24 |
| B | 5 | 2 | 22 | -40 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 13 |  |
| C | 2 | 0,5 | 113 | 200 |
| C | 3 | 1 | 163 | 100 |
| C | 4 | 1,5 | 75 | -176 |
| C | 5 | 2 | 28 | -94 |

Can you help me pls ?

Best Regards.

What I tried :

```
Slope = 
IF(HASONEVALUE(table[Users]),
VAR CurrentUser = SELECTEDVALUE(table[Users])
VAR CurrentIndex = SELECTEDVALUE(table[Index])
VAR PreviousIndex =
    CALCULATE (
    MAX ( table[Index] ),
    FILTER ( ALL(table), table[Users] = CurrentUser && table[Index] < CurrentIndex)
    )
RETURN
DIVIDE(LOOKUPVALUE(table[Y], table[Index], CurrentIndex)-LOOKUPVALUE(table[Y], table[Index], PreviousIndex),
LOOKUPVALUE(table[X], table[Index], CurrentIndex)-LOOKUPVALUE(table[X], table[Index], PreviousIndex)
,BLANK())
```

Comment: Have you consulted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885267/slope-powerpivot/51898274#51898274?

Comment: @qqtf Not the same question, I tried to calculate the slope between each two points, not the slope of the curve in general